# Order by field SQL state exception 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-order-by

I keep getting

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(questionid, 'sfname' , 'slname' , 'school' , 'grade' , 'addr' , 'city' , 'state' at line 1'
```

from this statement:

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM event_responses WHERE eventid= :eventid ORDER BY userid DESC, field (questionid, \''.implode("' , '", $columns1).'\')');
```

I echo'ed the statement inside and it looks fine to me:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM event_responses
WHERE eventid= :eventid
ORDER BY userid DESC,
      field (questionid, 'sfname' , 'slname' , 'school' , 'grade' , 'addr' , 'city' , 'state' , 'zip' , 'semail' , 'sphone' , 'pfname' , 'plname' , 'pemail' , 'pphone' , 'noattend' , 'regid' , 'submitDate' , 'attended' , 'regmethod')
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've hit a strange issue in MySQL:

> Note
>
> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and
>   the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish
>   between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen
>   to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function
>   arguments are permitted.

Remove the space after `field` so the expression is:

```
SELECT *
FROM event_responses
WHERE eventid = :eventid
ORDER BY userid DESC,
         field(questionid, 'sfname' , 'slname' , 'school' , 'grade' , 'addr' , 'city' , 'state' , 'zip' , 'semail' , 'sphone' , 'pfname' , 'plname' , 'pemail' , 'pphone' , 'noattend' , 'regid' , 'submitDate' , 'attended' , 'regmethod')
```

Comment: Personally, I never use spaces (as such) for any functions, be it PHP/SQL etc. (call it instinct?) Definitely worth a `+1` and then some ;-)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I cannot recreate this? It tried it via SQLFiddle and on a local install of MySQL, but it doesn't give me any problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6830/2 Have I made a mistake?

Comment: @Mr.Radical . . . Interesting.  I don't have MySQL near me right now, so I cannot test it except at SQL Fiddle (where it doesn't generate a problem).  I suspect removing the space fixed the problem, because the answer was accepted.